# How can I ignore time for NOW()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> I have a mysql database of entries
>   with dates. So what I want is to show
>   all the dates in my database and then
>   under each date, I want to show all
>   the entries in the database entered on
>   the specefic date. I am thinking of
>   two loops but I don't know how to
>   write the condition to display all the
>   dates in my database before I loop out
>   the entries under that date.

```
<?php

$sql = 'select start_date, name from events order by start_date';

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$prev_date = null;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {   if ($row['start_date'] != $prev_date) {
    echo "<h1>{$row['start_date']}</h1>"\n;
    $prev_date = $row['start_Date'];   }

  echo "<p>{$row['name']}</p>"; }

?>
```

In a previous question ([Looping out mysql data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395657/looping-out-mysql-data)), I resulted in using this code. It pulls the date and time from MYSQL, and I used NOW() to store both date and time. How can I make it ignore the time so I can achieve what I want?

Comment: Not too familiar with MySQL, but perhaps DATE(NOW()) will work.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the `NOW()` function - you are working with a `DATETIME` type, that is the relevant information here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as David Andres mentions in the comment, [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) extracts the date part of a date or datetime expression. so you can do the following:

```
<?php

$sql = 'SELECT DATE(start_date) AS start_date_date, name FROM events ORDER BY start_date';

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$prev_date = null;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  if ($row['start_date_date'] != $prev_date) {
    echo "<h1>$row[start_date_date]</h1>\n";
    $prev_date = $row['start_date_date'];
  }

  echo "<p>$row[name]</p>";
}
```

Comment: Works great! But it's not looping out all the dates for some reason. I'll try to figure it out! THANKS GUYS!

Answer (score 1):

Use [CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) instead of NOW().

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a condition like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE DATE(`start_date`) = '2009-09-09';
```

This'll get you all events from the database for Sep 9th 2009. I think that's what you're asking for, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Untested code that I will probably need someone to correct, but here goes:

**SQL to retrieve all the dates that exist in the table:**

```
$sql_get_dates = 'select start_date from events order by start_date distinct';
```

And, assuming *start_date* is a *DATETIME* type, the **SQL to get all events on a given date:**

```
$sql_get_events = 'select * from events where date(start_date) = "2009-08-09"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just selecting the date, you could use some of the MySQL time functions to truncate the date.

```
$sql = "select date_format(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as fstart_date, name from events order by start_date";
```

Of course, you'll have to change start_date to fstart_date within the PHP code.

Check out [the Mysql reference page for DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).